# Как разбить данные на дни, чтобы затем посчитать разницу и сложить?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть вот такая таблица
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне разбить данные на дни, чтобы затем посчитать разницу между каждым значением start и end и сложить их. 
Чтобы получилось например за 2015-09-07 что то вроде

2015-09-07 = 0 часов. 44 минуты

Comment: Какие типы данных в столбцах? А вообще SELECT end-start AS diff ... попробуйте.

Comment: А почему у вас `end` меньше `start`?

Comment: напишите буковками, чтобы можно было воспроизвести или, еще лучше, выложите на sqlfiddle

Comment: Visman прав, непонятно, что считать, если все старты больше ендов :(

Comment: Как понял, нужно по каждому дню считать сколько определенный ID затратил времени?
Это рабочее или проектирование?
Я бы выбрал другую схему - `id, contact_id, date, time`.
В `date` писать без времени, а в `time` как раз то время и считать ни чего не надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
  date(end) date,
  sec_to_time(sum(unix_timestamp(end)-unix_timestamp(start))) time
from t 
group by date
```

PS. Ничего "затем" считать не надо. База данных специально придумана для того, чтобы считать всё самой.
PPS. змея по-английски "sn**ake**"

Comment: Я так понял, ТС спрашивает про разбиение интервалов по дням и сложение в рамках одного дня.

Comment: Все  правильно. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм примерно такой: надо получить из бд пары `дата => +-1` где знак "+" для start'ов, и "-" для end'ов. Далее в php: отсортировать по возрастанию дат. Двигаться от самой старой даты к самой недавней.

Останавливаться на границах дней и подводить итоги: сколько на данный момент интервалов "активно" и сколько времени "выгорело" в текущем дне.